# how to set video from url in grid view and onclick item it will play video in full screen?

Tags: android, gridview, video-streaming, gallery

I have an application in which there is video tag onclick on that a new view open in which youtube video from urls are needed to show in grid or galery view. Than on click of video item it will play in full screen.

Thanx in advance.

Hope for your regards.

Answer (score -1):

You can start an Intent with the URL of your video for the gallery. For more information see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html